# Comparing Poker hands in Rust

Tags: programming-challenge, rust

I found this interesting challenge in Exercism.
This is my approach to comparing poker hands in Rust. I've strived for code clarity.
I wish I had figured out how to only implement Ord or PartialOrd, in the end I had to implement both for all structs.

It would be nice also if I had a way to avoid using the rank associated function on the enum HandType. My original approach was to establish constant values for each enum variant (StraightFlush = 9) but then I had to spread tons of explicit casts through the code and that looked dirty (hand.hadn_type as u8).

```
use std::cmp;
/// Given a list of poker hands, return a list of those hands which win.
///
/// Note the type signature: this function should return _the same_ reference to
/// the winning hand(s) as were passed in, not reconstructed strings which happen to be equal.
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Card {
    suit: char,
    numeric_value: u8,
}

impl Card {
    const ACE: u8 = 14;
    const KING: u8 = 13;
    const QUEEN: u8 = 12;
    const JACK: u8 = 11;

    fn new(str_card: &str) -> Result<Self, String> {
        let size = str_card.len();
        if !(2..=3).contains(&size) {
            return Err("Invalid card length".into());
        }

        let value = match size {
            2 => str_card.chars().next().unwrap(),
            3 => {
                let first_2: &str = &str_card[0..2];
                if first_2 == "10" {
                    'T'
                } else {
                    return Err(format!("Invalid card: {}", str_card));
                }
            }
            _ => panic!("Invalid card length"),
        };

        let suit = str_card.chars().nth(size - 1).unwrap();
        if suit != 'D' && suit != 'C' && suit != 'S' && suit != 'H' {
            return Err(format!("Invalid suit: {}", suit));
        }
        let numeric_value = match value {
            '2'..='9' => value.to_digit(10).unwrap() as u8,
            'T' => 10,
            'J' => Card::JACK,
            'Q' => Card::QUEEN,
            'K' => Card::KING,
            'A' => Card::ACE,
            _ => return Err("Invalid value".into()),
        };

        Ok(Self {
            suit,
            numeric_value,
        })
    }
}

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct HighCardData {
    cards: Vec<u8>,
}

impl HighCardData {
    fn new(cards: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        Self { cards }
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for HighCardData {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(&other))
    }
}

impl Ord for HighCardData {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        for i in (0..self.cards.len()).rev() {
            let self_value = self.cards[i];
            let other_value = other.cards[i];

            if self_value != other_value {
                return self_value.cmp(&other_value);
            }
        }
        Ordering::Equal
    }
}

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct OnePairData {
    pair_value: u8,
    remaining_cards: Vec<u8>,
}

impl OnePairData {
    fn new(pair_value: u8, remaining_cards: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        Self {
            pair_value,
            remaining_cards,
        }
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for OnePairData {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(&other))
    }
}

impl Ord for OnePairData {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        let cmp_pair_value = self.pair_value.cmp(&other.pair_value);
        if cmp_pair_value != Ordering::Equal {
            return cmp_pair_value;
        }
        HighCardData::new(self.remaining_cards.clone())
            .cmp(&HighCardData::new(other.remaining_cards.clone()))
    }
}

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct TwoPairsData {
    high_pair_value: u8,
    low_pair_value: u8,
    remaining_card: u8,
}

impl TwoPairsData {
    fn new(high_pair_value: u8, low_pair_value: u8, remaining_card: u8) -> Self {
        Self {
            high_pair_value,
            low_pair_value,
            remaining_card,
        }
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for TwoPairsData {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(&other))
    }
}

impl Ord for TwoPairsData {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        let cmp_high_pair_value = self.high_pair_value.cmp(&other.high_pair_value);
        if cmp_high_pair_value != Ordering::Equal {
            return cmp_high_pair_value;
        }
        let cmp_low_pair_value = self.low_pair_value.cmp(&other.low_pair_value);
        if cmp_low_pair_value != Ordering::Equal {
            return cmp_low_pair_value;
        }
        self.remaining_card.cmp(&other.remaining_card)
    }
}

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct ThreeOfAKindData {
    three_of_a_kind_value: u8,
    remaining_cards: Vec<u8>,
}

impl ThreeOfAKindData {
    fn new(three_of_a_kind_value: u8, remaining_cards: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        Self {
            three_of_a_kind_value,
            remaining_cards,
        }
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for ThreeOfAKindData {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(&other))
    }
}

impl Ord for ThreeOfAKindData {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        let cmp_value = self.three_of_a_kind_value.cmp(&other.three_of_a_kind_value);
        if cmp_value != Ordering::Equal {
            return cmp_value;
        }
        HighCardData::new(self.remaining_cards.clone())
            .cmp(&HighCardData::new(other.remaining_cards.clone()))
    }
}

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct StraightData {
    cards: Vec<u8>,
}

impl StraightData {
    fn new(cards: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        Self { cards }
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for StraightData {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(&other))
    }
}

impl Ord for StraightData {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        let sv = &self.cards;
        let ov = &other.cards;
        let self_vec: Vec<u8>;
        if sv[0] == 2 && sv[sv.len() - 1] == Card::ACE {
            self_vec = vec![1, sv[0], sv[1], sv[2], sv[3]];
        } else {
            self_vec = sv.clone();
        }
        let other_vec: Vec<u8>;
        if ov[0] == 2 && ov[ov.len() - 1] == Card::ACE {
            other_vec = vec![1, ov[0], ov[1], ov[2], ov[3]];
        } else {
            other_vec = ov.clone();
        }

        HighCardData::new(self_vec).cmp(&HighCardData::new(other_vec))
    }
}

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct FullHouseData {
    three_of_a_kind_value: u8,
    pair_value: u8,
}

impl FullHouseData {
    fn new(three_of_a_kind_value: u8, pair_value: u8) -> Self {
        Self {
            three_of_a_kind_value,
            pair_value,
        }
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for FullHouseData {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(&other))
    }
}

impl Ord for FullHouseData {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        let cmp_three = self.three_of_a_kind_value.cmp(&other.three_of_a_kind_value);
        if cmp_three != Ordering::Equal {
            return cmp_three;
        }
        self.pair_value.cmp(&other.pair_value)
    }
}

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct FourOfAKindData {
    four_of_a_kind_value: u8,
    remaining_card: u8,
}

impl FourOfAKindData {
    fn new(four_of_a_kind_value: u8, remaining_card: u8) -> Self {
        Self {
            four_of_a_kind_value,
            remaining_card,
        }
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for FourOfAKindData {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(&other))
    }
}

impl Ord for FourOfAKindData {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        let cmp = self.four_of_a_kind_value.cmp(&other.four_of_a_kind_value);
        if cmp != Ordering::Equal {
            return cmp;
        }
        self.remaining_card.cmp(&other.remaining_card)
    }
}

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Ord, PartialOrd, Debug)]
enum HandType {
    StraightFlush(HighCardData),
    FourOfAKind(FourOfAKindData),
    FullHouse(FullHouseData),
    Flush(HighCardData),
    Straight(StraightData),
    ThreeOfAKind(ThreeOfAKindData),
    TwoPairs(TwoPairsData),
    OnePair(OnePairData),
    HighCard(HighCardData),
}

impl HandType {
    fn rank(&self) -> u8 {
        match self {
            HandType::StraightFlush(_) => 9,
            HandType::FourOfAKind(_) => 8,
            HandType::FullHouse(_) => 7,
            HandType::Flush(_) => 6,
            HandType::Straight(_) => 5,
            HandType::ThreeOfAKind(_) => 4,
            HandType::TwoPairs(_) => 3,
            HandType::OnePair(_) => 2,
            HandType::HighCard(_) => 1,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Eq, Debug)]
struct PokerHand<'a> {
    str_hand: &'a str,
    hand_type: HandType,
}

impl<'a> PokerHand<'a> {
    fn new_from_values(str_hand: &'a str, hand_type: HandType) -> Self {
        Self {
            str_hand,
            hand_type,
        }
    }

    fn new(str_hand: &'a str) -> Result<Self, String> {
        let mut cards: Vec<Card> = Vec::new();
        let split = str_hand.split(' ');
        for s in split {
            let possible_new_card = Card::new(s);
            let new_card = match possible_new_card {
                Ok(card) => card,
                Err(_) => return Err("Cannot create card".into()),
            };
            cards.push(new_card);
        }

        cards.sort_by(|a, b| a.numeric_value.cmp(&b.numeric_value));

        let first_card = &cards[0];
        let mut previous_suit = first_card.suit;
        let mut previous_value = 0;
        let mut suit_counter = 0;
        let mut straight_counter = 1;

        let mut kind_count_map: HashMap<u8, usize> = HashMap::new();

        let mut starts_at_two = false;

        for card in &cards {
            if card.suit == previous_suit {
                suit_counter += 1;
            } else {
                suit_counter = 0;
                previous_suit = card.suit;
            }
            if previous_value == 0 {
                if card.numeric_value == 2 {
                    starts_at_two = true;
                } else {
                    previous_value = card.numeric_value;
                }
            } else if card.numeric_value == (previous_value + 1) {
                straight_counter += 1;
            }
            if card.numeric_value != previous_value {
                previous_value = card.numeric_value;
            }
            *kind_count_map.entry(card.numeric_value).or_insert(0) += 1;
        }
        let is_flush = suit_counter == 5;
        let is_straight = PokerHand::is_straight(
            straight_counter,
            starts_at_two,
            cards[cards.len() - 1].numeric_value,
        );

        let sorted_numeric_values: Vec<u8> = cards.iter().map(|c| c.numeric_value).collect();

        if is_flush {
            if is_straight {
                return Ok(PokerHand::new_from_values(
                    str_hand,
                    HandType::StraightFlush(HighCardData::new(sorted_numeric_values)),
                ));
            } else {
                return Ok(PokerHand::new_from_values(
                    str_hand,
                    HandType::Flush(HighCardData::new(sorted_numeric_values)),
                ));
            }
        }

        if is_straight {
            return Ok(PokerHand::new_from_values(
                str_hand,
                HandType::Straight(StraightData::new(sorted_numeric_values)),
            ));
        }

        let mut has_three = false;
        let mut pair_count = 0;

        let mut three_of_a_kind_value: u8 = 0;

        let mut pairs: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

        for (key, value) in kind_count_map {
            if value == 4 {
                let the_other_card: Vec<&u8> = sorted_numeric_values
                    .iter()
                    .filter(|v| *v != &key)
                    .collect();
                return Ok(PokerHand::new_from_values(
                    str_hand,
                    HandType::FourOfAKind(FourOfAKindData::new(key, *the_other_card[0])),
                ));
            } else if value == 3 {
                has_three = true;
                three_of_a_kind_value = key;
            } else if value == 2 {
                pairs.push(key);
                pair_count += 1;
            }
        }

        if has_three {
            if pair_count == 1 {
                return Ok(PokerHand::new_from_values(
                    str_hand,
                    HandType::FullHouse(FullHouseData::new(three_of_a_kind_value, pairs[0])),
                ));
            } else {
                let remaining_cards: Vec<u8> = sorted_numeric_values
                    .into_iter()
                    .filter(|v| *v != three_of_a_kind_value)
                    .collect();
                return Ok(PokerHand::new_from_values(
                    str_hand,
                    HandType::ThreeOfAKind(ThreeOfAKindData::new(
                        three_of_a_kind_value,
                        remaining_cards,
                    )),
                ));
            }
        }

        if pair_count == 2 {
            let highest_pair = cmp::max(pairs[0], pairs[1]);
            let lowest_pair = cmp::min(pairs[0], pairs[1]);
            let the_other_card: Vec<&u8> = sorted_numeric_values
                .iter()
                .filter(|v| *v != &highest_pair && *v != &lowest_pair)
                .collect();
            return Ok(PokerHand::new_from_values(
                str_hand,
                HandType::TwoPairs(TwoPairsData::new(
                    highest_pair,
                    lowest_pair,
                    *the_other_card[0],
                )),
            ));
        }

        if pair_count == 1 {
            let pair_value = pairs[0];
            let remaining_cards: Vec<u8> = sorted_numeric_values
                .into_iter()
                .filter(|v| *v != pair_value)
                .collect();
            return Ok(PokerHand::new_from_values(
                str_hand,
                HandType::OnePair(OnePairData::new(pair_value, remaining_cards)),
            ));
        }

        Ok(PokerHand::new_from_values(
            str_hand,
            HandType::HighCard(HighCardData::new(sorted_numeric_values)),
        ))
    }

    fn is_straight(
        straight_counter: usize,
        starts_at_two: bool,
        last_card_numeric_value: u8,
    ) -> bool {
        straight_counter == 5
            || PokerHand::is_straight_starting_with_ace(
                straight_counter,
                starts_at_two,
                last_card_numeric_value,
            )
    }

    fn is_straight_starting_with_ace(
        straight_counter: usize,
        starts_at_two: bool,
        last_card_numeric_value: u8,
    ) -> bool {
        straight_counter == 4 && starts_at_two && last_card_numeric_value == Card::ACE
    }
}

impl<'a> Ord for PokerHand<'a> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        let rank_cmp = self.hand_type.rank().cmp(&other.hand_type.rank());
        if rank_cmp != Ordering::Equal {
            return rank_cmp;
        }
        self.hand_type.cmp(&other.hand_type)
    }
}

impl<'a> PartialOrd for PokerHand<'a> {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl<'a> PartialEq for PokerHand<'a> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.hand_type == other.hand_type
    }
}

pub fn winning_hands<'a>(hands: &[&'a str]) -> Option<Vec<&'a str>> {
    let size = hands.len();
    if size == 0 {
        return None;
    }
    if size == 1 {
        return Some(vec![hands[0]]);
    }

    let mut processed_hands: Vec<PokerHand> = Vec::new();

    for hand in hands {
        let processed_hand = match PokerHand::new(hand) {
            Ok(processed_hand) => processed_hand,
            Err(_) => return None,
        };

        processed_hands.push(processed_hand);
    }

    processed_hands.sort();
    processed_hands.reverse();

    let mut result = Vec::new();
    let highest_hand = &processed_hands[0];
    result.push(highest_hand.str_hand);

    for processed_hand in processed_hands.iter().skip(1) {
        if processed_hand.cmp(highest_hand) == Ordering::Equal {
            result.push(processed_hand.str_hand);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    Some(result)
}
```

Comment: If you're using `char` for suits, you should definitely use `'♠'`, `'♥'`, `'♣'`, and `'♦'` instead of `'S'`, `'H'`, `'C'`, `'D'` ;-)

Answer (score 6):

## General observations

- `rustfmt`-compliant formatting
- no warnings
- `#[derive(Debug)]` on everything that might be useful to debug-print
- no tests or `main`  (I guess this is built in to Exercism?) Some of the remainder of this review might be a little off base because I wasn't able to test the code.

## Specific observations

### Use newtypes and/or enums for restricted values

```
struct Card {
    suit: char,
    numeric_value: u8,
}
```

`char` and `u8` don't really tell you much about those values. What about some enums? `enum Suit { Heart, Spade, Diamond, Club }` would work great for `suit`, and for `value` you could use a C-style `enum Rank { Two = 2, Three, ... King, Ace }` (C-style enums can be cast to integers with `as` for the straight check). It might feel a little weird writing out names for the numbers from 2 to 10, but it's not as if they're going to change any time soon, and you only have to do it twice (once in the definition and once for parsing, on which more later).

```
impl Card {
    const ACE: u8 = 14;
    const KING: u8 = 13;
    const QUEEN: u8 = 12;
    const JACK: u8 = 11;
```

Making `Rank` an enum would eliminate these `const`s as well.

### Parsing and initialization

```
    fn new(str_card: &str) -> Result<Self, String> {
```

Consider implementing `FromStr` instead of having a `new` function that parses a string. I would usually reserve the name `new` for a trivial constructor, or one that only does validation, not parsing.

### Parsing

```
        let size = str_card.len();
        if !(2..=3).contains(&size) {
            return Err("Invalid card length".into());
        }
```

This part is a little weird because `len()` returns *byte* counts but you go on to parse *characters*, which is the same thing here but only because all the characters are in the ASCII subset. It's not exactly wrong, but it's fragile; if you wanted to support input like `"A♠"`, it would need a full rewrite. Consider using string methods to match against substrings instead of picking it apart character by character.

#### Note on error types

`String` is fine as an error type for a self-contained program. For a library you'd want to have a custom error type and return values like `MyError::InvalidLength(n)`.

```
        let value = match size {
            2 => str_card.chars().next().unwrap(), // this is the second time you check the size of the string
            3 => {
                let first_2: &str = &str_card[0..2]; // multi-byte inputs will panic here
                if first_2 == "10" {
                    'T'
                } else {
                    return Err(format!("Invalid card: {}", str_card));
                }
            }
            _ => panic!("Invalid card length"), // this is the third time you check the size of the string
        };

        let suit = str_card.chars().nth(size - 1).unwrap(); // this is the FOURTH time you check the size of the string
```

Here's one example of doing something that kind of solves a problem, but doesn't really solve the *whole* problem. Because you check the length of the string, but don't validate the contents at this point, you will have to validate the contents in a second pass, during which you will have to essentially validate the length again. Forget validating the size in advance: chunk it up as best you can and parse the chunks individually.

#### Enums again

```
        if suit != 'D' && suit != 'C' && suit != 'S' && suit != 'H' {
            return Err(format!("Invalid suit: {}", suit));
        }
```

Okay, it's validated, but `suit` is still just a `char`, so there's no type-level record of this validation being performed. A suit is one of four things; a character could be anything. I think you get the point, let me hit it one more time:

```
        let numeric_value = match value {
            '2'..='9' => value.to_digit(10).unwrap() as u8,
            'T' => 10,
            'J' => Card::JACK,
            'Q' => Card::QUEEN,
            'K' => Card::KING,
            'A' => Card::ACE,
            _ => return Err("Invalid value".into()),
        };
```

Same here: you could use a `struct Rank(u8);` or an `enum Rank {...}`. If the parsing here is complex you could also implement `FromStr` for `Rank` and `Suit`, and defer to that, instead of implementing it in-line.

Let's skip ahead a bit...

### `HandType` and ordering

```
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Ord, PartialOrd, Debug)]
enum HandType {
    StraightFlush(HighCardData),
    FourOfAKind(FourOfAKindData),
    FullHouse(FullHouseData),
    Flush(HighCardData),
    Straight(StraightData),
    ThreeOfAKind(ThreeOfAKindData),
    TwoPairs(TwoPairsData),
    OnePair(OnePairData),
    HighCard(HighCardData),
}
```

This enum is unnecessarily complicated. In the first case, it's smart to take advantage of the built-in behavior of `#[derive(PartialOrd)]`, but you've made things unnecessarily hard on yourself by putting these in descending order of rank, so you can't rely on `PartialOrd` to give the ordering you want: you have to call `rank`, compare that first, *then* compare the rest of the contents. If you just list them in increasing order, you can make `derive(PartialOrd)` do the right thing without any additional work.

Secondly, `StraightFlush` should hold `StraightData` instead of `HighCardData`; as written, you're treating an 5-high straight flush as higher than a king-high straight flush. You wrote the logic for this but you only used it for "normal" straights (I'm probably butchering the vocabulary here, sorry, I don't play poker).

Furthermore, `HighCardData`'s `Ord` implementation is used, directly or indirectly, in six of the nine variants, which is a strong hint that there's unexploited symmetry in this data structure. Let's look at that...

#### `HighCardData`

```
impl Ord for HighCardData {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        for i in (0..self.cards.len()).rev() {
            let self_value = self.cards[i];
            let other_value = other.cards[i];

            if self_value != other_value {
                return self_value.cmp(&other_value);
            }
        }
        Ordering::Equal
    }
}
```

Hmm... so the only difference between this and the default `Ord` behavior for `Vec` is that it's in reverse order? Why not reverse the cards in the `new` function, and simply `#[derive]` it?

#### `OnePairData`, etc.

```
impl Ord for OnePairData {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        
        let cmp_pair_value = self.pair_value.cmp(&other.pair_value);
        // (note `Ordering` has `then` and `then_with` methods that you might use here)
        if cmp_pair_value != Ordering::Equal {
            return cmp_pair_value;
        }
        HighCardData::new(self.remaining_cards.clone())
            .cmp(&HighCardData::new(other.remaining_cards.clone()))
    }
}
```

This would also work as `#[derive]`d if the `remaining_cards` were kept sorted in descending order of value. In fact, this is a common theme among most of the `Ord` implementations so I won't go through the rest of them one by one. `StraightData` is a bit special, though:

#### `StraightData`

```
impl Ord for StraightData {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        let sv = &self.cards;
        let ov = &other.cards;
        let self_vec: Vec<u8>;
        if sv[0] == 2 && sv[sv.len() - 1] == Card::ACE {
            self_vec = vec![1, sv[0], sv[1], sv[2], sv[3]];
        } else {
            self_vec = sv.clone();
        }
        let other_vec: Vec<u8>;
        if ov[0] == 2 && ov[ov.len() - 1] == Card::ACE {
            other_vec = vec![1, ov[0], ov[1], ov[2], ov[3]];
        } else {
            other_vec = ov.clone();
        }

        HighCardData::new(self_vec).cmp(&HighCardData::new(other_vec))
    }
}
```

This one might need a little more thought: if you sort the cards in descending order by rank, treating the ace as a 1, then the `#[derive]`d (`Partial`)`Ord` behavior (when the ace is treated as a 14) will be correct.

```
[K Q J 10 A]  <- Ace-high straight sorted in descending order (with ace as 1)
[K Q J 10 9]  <- King-high straight sorted in descending order
```

#### Using card ordering to your advantage

There's a common theme here: if you sort the cards in the "correct" order when creating `HandType`, you don't actually need any custom comparison code; it can all be `#[derive]`d. This suggests to me an alternate implementation:

> ```
> #[derive(Debug, Eq, Ord, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
> struct Hand {
>     kind: HandType,
>     cards: Vec<u8>,  // or Vec<Rank>, or just Vec<Card>
> }
> // If, when creating `Hand`, we detect `kind` and use it to determine how to order 
> // `cards`, then we don't need to write any custom (Partial)Ord code.
> // Note none of these variants have data -- the cards are in `cards`.
> #[derive(Debug, Eq, Ord, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
> enum HandType {
>     HighCard,
>     OnePair,
>     TwoPairs,
>     ThreeOfAKind,
>     Straight,
>     Flush,
>     FullHouse,
>     FourOfAKind,
>     StraightFlush,
> }
> ```

### `PokerHand`

```
struct PokerHand<'a> {
    str_hand: &'a str,
    hand_type: HandType,
}
```

Minor quibble: assuming I'm willingly using a library that has to do with card games, I'm probably going to know that `Hand` is a hand of cards and not a primate appendage. Prefixing it with `Poker` doesn't, in my opinion, improve readability. Rust, unlike C, has a namespace system with fine-grained visibility controls, so we don't need to worry about it ever conflicting with some other library type also named `Hand`.

One thing I would not do here is keep the `str_hand` as part of this struct. The string is useless once the `hand_type` has been parsed out of it: you are keeping it around for the sake of `winning_hands`, but that really shouldn't be any concern of `PokerHand`. It doesn't come into play during analysis. Just keep track of the parsed data, and let `winning_hands` remember where it came from (more on this later).

### Parsing and validating a `PokerHand`

```
impl<'a> PokerHand<'a> {
    fn new(str_hand: &'a str) -> Result<Self, String> {
```

This is another dense `new` function that blends the responsibilities of parsing and initialization. I'd make `new` take a `Vec<Card>` and do just the hand analysis, and again write a `FromStr` implementation that parses into a `Vec<Card>` and then calls `new`.

```
        let split = str_hand.split(' ');
```

Consider using `split_whitespace` instead.

```
        cards.sort_by(|a, b| a.numeric_value.cmp(&b.numeric_value));
```

You have a lot of lines that look something like this. You should usually use `sort_unstable_by` when the original ordering of equal values is unimportant. It won't likely give a big speed boost (although it might for some datasets), but it is a form of documentation about your assumptions. Also note that you can use `u8::cmp(&a.numeric_value, &b.numeric_value)` (or `Ord::cmp`), which I like better because it looks more symmetric, but there's nothing wrong with the way you've written it either.

#### State machines

```
        let mut previous_suit = first_card.suit;
        let mut previous_value = 0;
        let mut suit_counter = 0;
        let mut straight_counter = 1;

        let mut kind_count_map: HashMap<u8, usize> = HashMap::new();

        let mut starts_at_two = false;
```

This is a state machine with six state registers. I personally find that, while it's possible to keep track of five "things" at a time mentally for short periods, the realistic limit should usually be four. Six things is just too many, unless they have some structure to them that allows you to treat them as groups of things (`(x, y, z)` triplets, or something like that). I apply this general principle not just to state machines, but to function arguments, type parameters, and shopping lists. I would do one of two things here:

1. (recommended) Break a complex state machine into smaller ones. Basically, do several passes over the cards instead of trying to do it all in a single loop. Since you're looping over a slice that is already in memory, resetting the loop is essentially free. Since there are commonalities between the checks you need to do, you might exploit some of those symmetries to skip parts of later loops. But you don't need to do it all in one shot.
2. Combine several state registers into a struct, simplifying the outer loop by pushing the complexity down into the struct's methods. Call it something like `CardSummary` and give it methods like `straight(&self) -> Option<Vec<Card>>` and `full_house(&self) -> Option<[Card; 3], [Card; 2]>` to call when you're done. This has the advantage of not requiring iterating over the cards more than once; however, it's probably not necessary in this case.

```
            if card.numeric_value != previous_value {
                previous_value = card.numeric_value;
            }
```

This branch is extraneous. Just `previous_value = card.numeric_value;` should be fine. Making this change reveals that the `else` a few lines up is also redundant and can be eliminated as well.

```
        let mut has_three = false;
        let mut pair_count = 0;

        let mut three_of_a_kind_value: u8 = 0;

        let mut pairs: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
```

One non-trivial state machine per function, please.

This one can be easily reduced to two state registers, because `has_three` is just the discriminant of the `Option` that should contain `three_of_a_kind_value`, and `pair_count` is just `pairs.len()`.

All the logic embedded in `if has_three`, `if pair_count == 2`, etc. should be wrapped in smaller functions with descriptive names.

### `winning_hands`

```
pub fn winning_hands<'a>(hands: &[&'a str]) -> Option<Vec<&'a str>> {
```

I assume Exercism gives you this signature to fill in, so you don't have the ability to control it. However, it's not very good for several reasons. `Option<Vec>` is weird because `Vec` can be empty, and in this case an empty output is the perfectly logical response to an empty input, so it should really just be `Vec`. Except that you're also using `None` to indicate an error condition, for which you should be using `Result` instead of `Option`. Moreover, the interesting part of this is taking a bunch of hands and deciding which one(s) win: not the parsing of hands from strings. So I would first write a function with the signature I *want* to write, and then write `winning_hands` to use it internally.

Here's the function signature I'd implement: `fn(&[PokerHand]) -> Vec<usize>` (the `usize`s are the indices of the winning hands in the input slice). Because it returns `usize`s, you can easily implement `winning_hands` without having to store the input strings in the `PokerHand`s. Bonus challenge: figure out how to accept any iterable of `&PokerHand`s.

```
    processed_hands.sort();
    processed_hands.reverse();
```

`processed_hands.sort_by(|a, b| Ord::cmp(b, a))` (note the reversal of `b` and `a`) or `processed_hands.sort_by(|a, b| a.cmp(b).reverse())`.

```
    let highest_hand = &processed_hands[0];
    // ...
    for processed_hand in processed_hands.iter().skip(1) {
```

Consider using `processed_hands.split_first()` in situations like this. Not sure if it buys you much in this particular case.

Comment: Thank you times a thousand. This was very generous and professional. I have this up on my github and I'll carefully consider your great recommendations and apply them over there.